# Can a bounty be extended due to long read only mode?

Tags: discussion, bounties, read-only

If a site is in read-only mode for about one hour (for example), will open bounties be extended by one hour, or have I lost an hour?

Comment: Fair question, since you just want to discuss this and not asking to actually extend, +1

Comment: @ShadowWizard i'm always happy to start interesting discussions on SE, it's a nice thing :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you mean by "lost 1 hour" - your post was still readable during the read-only period, so anyone who would have answered was able to view it, answering it after the read-only finished.

But to answer your question - the bounty will not get extended. It is calculated from the time it was opened.

Comment: Trivia question: what about a bounty that expire in the middle of read only mode, i.e. the user who started it can't award it? Extreme edge case, but still.. anything such user can do?

Comment: @Sha - yeah, extreme edge case. Worthy of flagging for moderator attention.

Comment: Well, just make sure read only mode won't last for long time and all will be good. :D

Comment: @Oded thank you for your answer :)!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Also, bounties can be awarded to answers that come in during the grace period. So unless the bounty donator accepted an answer or is quicker than you after the read-only mode has ended, you already have a sort-of extension.