# Is there a policy for extending bounty periods in cases where there is SE network outage or maintenance?

Tags: discussion, bounties, outage, maintenance

If I start a bounty, I expect that bounty to last 7 days unless I award the bounty before the time of expiry. What happens if there is Stack Exchange Network maintenance or outage during that time? Is that time lost or am I given extra time on my bounty equal to the duration of the downtime?

There is an [existing answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248673/722486) that addresses bounty extension on sites that are **read-only** for some time, and it makes sense -- there is no need to extend a bounty if the question can still be read. My question only pertains to situations in which network downtime prevents access to my bountied question.

Reading through the posts on [stackstatus.net](https://stackstatus.net/), I realize that site-wide maintenance usually lasts a few minutes and is therefore inconsequential. Moreover, I know longer outages are rare, but I'm still curious if there is a policy in place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bounties should not be active during readonly mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234306/bounties-should-not-be-active-during-readonly-mode)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a bounty be extended due to long read only mode?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248671/can-a-bounty-be-extended-due-to-long-read-only-mode/248673#comment814377_248673) - answer in a comment on the answer: In the unlikely event that you can not see your question or otherwise feel there is an unfair situation with respect to your bounty simply custom flag for moderator attention.

Comment: FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work 
- Moderator Tools:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27103/282094

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, they won't. Essentially you're paying reputation so that the question is bountied for the next 7*24=168 hours. As you say, outages are rare and any attempts to compensate for them would be hard to implement and not outweigh the benefits. Even exceptionally long downtimes of an hour would be less than 1% of the total duration of the bounty.

Comment: + the grace period. If SE is down for more than a day... things are baaaaad